# Unity C# Multiplying arrays

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am working on a script for unity which takes arrays of numbers (each index only has a number from 0-9.  If the number goes above 10, it takes 10 away and increases the [index + 1] value by 1. so, if i wanted a number that was 850, my list would be 
`List<int> Money = new List<int>() { 0, 5, 8, 0, 0 };`

This works, my problem is i am unable to figure out a way to multiply two of these together and get a final answer, i would normally just use regular numbers, but i want this system to be able to go past unity's int limit and scientific notation limit of e+300.

Any help is greatly appreciate, thank you. Have a nice day!

Edit: if this isn't clear enough, here is an example

`List1 = {0, 5, 8, 0}`
`List2 = {3, 6, 3, 0}`

i need to multiply list1 and list2 to get

`List3 = {0, 5, 5, 6, 0, 3}`

Since 850 * 363 = 306,550

Comment: Can you give us a concrete example?  And why is 850 `0, 5, 8, 0, 0` instead of `0, 8, 5, 0 ,0`?

Comment: Why not use BigInteger to represent very very large numbers instead of rolling your own?

Comment: 2 things, 1, i am not sure what bit-integer is (also, im trying to create my own so i can learn, im taking a class on unity and im ahead and no one else can help me, so im going to the internet for support), and 2nd, i have it as 0,5,8 because (a,b,c) a is the 1s place, b is the 10s place, c is the 100s place, d would be 1000s place, etc...

Comment: Concrete Example: {0, 5, 8 , 0, 0} * {3, 6, 3, 0, 0}, i have made attempts, but i can't multiply straight across and im not sure how to multiply by each number, without getting an error

Comment: It's `BigInteger`, not `bit-integer`, and you could google it if you aren't familiar with it.  You should add the content of those comments to your question, as they're necessary for understanding it.

Comment: autocorrect changed it to bit-integer, i know what you were talking about though, do you have any knowledge on how to make this yourself?

Comment: You said you weren't sure what it is, now you say you know what I was talking about.  I'm confused.  For now I'm trying to help you improve your question.

Comment: When i say i know what you are talking about, i mean i had googled it and understood what you meant about BitInteger

Comment: Have you tried the "long" primitive? It is double an int, and is also known as Int64.

Answer (score 1):

To actually give an answer to this in fact quite interesting learning task: I would suggest implementing traditional "manual" multiplication: https://www.wikihow.com/Do-Long-Multiplication
Not sure what (internal) libraries like BigInteger do under the hood, but theoretically this would work with your lists because it allows you to go step by step through 10s place, 100s place, 1000s place and so on.

Comment: After a few hours of attempts, i finally got it working, and i did pretty much that, i did basic long multiplication that i learned as a kid, and took it into arrays, and eventually i got it to work, thanks for the help!

Comment: @KingDuck Congrats! It feels great to solve a tough problem :) However ensure that you do not really use this when performance is critical because most likely BigInteger has better hardware acceleration.